# How to make a function that keeps a total inside the main method?

Tags: java

I basically need to make a function that accomplishes a basic sum (like x += y). My limitations are that the function can't actually take anything as the input, and that it needs to keep track of stuff through a for loop. I've coded an attempt at it (it is only a small chunk of a larger assignment), but mine seems to reset at every loop through; it only ever outputs whatever value() equals, and doesn't keep track of itself inbetween iterations of the loop. I've rewritten some stuff to take out what doesn't need to be in there, as without it there would be quite a bit of chaff. My function references a value() function, but that isn't important to my problem; just know that it checks the value of something that changes randomly between iterations, and returns that value as a double. BenchmarkTimer is simply the class of the overall series of functions.

```
public class BenchmarkTimer{ 

    public double total;

    public double total(){
        total += value();
        return total;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int l = 1; l <= 4; l++){
            BenchmarkTimer timer1 = new BenchmarkTimer();
            timer1.value();
            System.out.println(timer1.total());
        }
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to get happen is that timer1.total should be returning the total of the values added up across all iterations. If the first value obtained was 2, it should output 2. The second time through if given a value of 3, I want it to output 5.

Right now, it simply outputs whatever the value gained from that loop is. Also, ideally, I don't want moving the declaration of timer1 outside of the loop to the be the solution, as that will require me re-coding quite a bit of other stuff to accommodate. If its the only way then thats fine, but if there are different solutions to be had I'd be glad to hear them. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try newing `BenchmarkTimer timer1` before the `for-loop`

Comment: Is that the only practical solution? I was pretty sure that would work, but it screws with the rest of my functions so I was really hoping there was another way to do it.

Comment: I can't know if it will screw the rest of your functions, but you could try making class variable `total` a static variable. Then you could keep the `for` loop as you posted it.

Comment: @Steven declare your ints outside the function (so it's just n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / for l = 0 ) .. you're resetting them...?

Comment: Making the total static solved my problem pretty nicely; there is a little but I need to rework because of that, but not nearly as much as leaving it inside the loop. Thank you for the help Abra and everyone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ideally, I don't want moving the declaration of timer1 outside of the loop to the be the solution

Well, without doing that, then you could make a completely separate variable

```
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double d = 0;
    for (int l = 1; l <= 4; l++){
        BenchmarkTimer timer1 = new BenchmarkTimer();
        d += timer1.value();
        System.out.println(timer1.total());
    }
    System.out.println(d);
```

Otherwise, yes, that is the ideal solution because without that, then you're resetting the timer.